# Trying to create a Custom column in power Bi

Tags: powerbi

I am trying to put this excel formula into Power BI (replaced the cell reference with the field references) but it doesn't like round up or max. Any idea how to fix this?

```
ROUNDUP(MAX(
IF([Wk 1 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 1 Av]-([Wk 1 Tot]*0.1)),
IF([Wk 2 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 2 Av]-([Wk 2 Tot]*0.1)),
IF([Wk 3 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 3 Av]-([Wk 3 Tot]*0.1)),
IF([Wk 4 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 4 Av]-([Wk 4 Tot]*0.1)),
IF([Wk 5 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 5 Av]-([Wk 5 Tot]*0.1)),
IF([Wk 06 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 06 Av]-([Wk 06 Tot]*0.1)),
IF([Wk 07 Tot]=0,-100,[Wk 07 Av]-([Wk 07 Tot]*0.1))),0)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is not as straight forward as in excel. In Power BI, the max function is allowed a maximum of only tow arguments. There are two ways to tackle this:

1. Write nested loops of max function with two arguments each
2. Create a maximum statistic in the power query itself (This might involve creation of calculated fields for all your if conditions)

Both the above listed methods are highlighted in detail in the below link. Hope this helps.

https://community.powerbi.com/t5/Desktop/Get-MAX-value-of-dates-across-multiple-columns/td-p/614305

Answer (score 0):

Here is a DAX equivalent using [MAXX](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/maxx-function-dax) and [table constructor](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dax/table-constructor).

```
= ROUNDUP (
    MAXX (
        {
            IF ( [Wk 1 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 1 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 1 Tot] ),
            IF ( [Wk 2 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 2 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 2 Tot] ),
            IF ( [Wk 3 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 3 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 3 Tot] ),
            IF ( [Wk 4 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 4 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 4 Tot] ),
            IF ( [Wk 5 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 5 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 5 Tot] ),
            IF ( [Wk 6 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 6 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 6 Tot] ),
            IF ( [Wk 7 Tot] = 0, -100, [Wk 7 Avg] - 0.1 * [Wk 7 Tot] )
        },
        [Value]
    ),
    0
)
```

Also, please keep in mind this is not the best practice. You should consider to [unpivot](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/unpivot-columns-power-query-0f7bad4b-9ea1-49c1-9d95-f588221c7098) the data before loading to the Data Model (typically using Power Query).